# Have Excel sort by time?

Tags: excel

For some reason, when I try to sort excel data by time, Excel ignores me and does whatever it wants.

I have a column that shows millitary time (13:00 instead of 1:00 PM) and all the time stamps have the date 1/0/0.

When I try to sort the column by value, Excel does not do that.
How Can I get the column to display:

```
10:00 
13:24
13:44
```

Instead of:

```
10:00
13:44
13:24
```

(for example)

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `How Can I get the column to display: 10:00 13:24 13:44

Instead of: 10:00 13:44 13:24`

Comment: My guess is that the dates that are not seen are different.  Change the column to "General"  You should have numbers that are all less then 1.

Comment: Since a date in excel measures the number of days since January 1st 1900 (PC), when the cell is formatted as general you will get an integer.  Fo the time serial that excel  uses, you will get the fraction of a day.  so 0.5 will correspond to noon and 0.25 will correspond to 06:00. or 6:00 AM.  As such, if you truly only have time in your column, every number will be less than 1 and greater than or equal to 0.  If you note you have a number greater than or equal to 1, then you also have a date attached to your time.  This will throw off your sort for a column formatted to only display time.

Comment: since you claim some of the data is sorted out of order when the all have a date of 1/0/0 attached to them, I would suggest posting a screen shot of the faulty sort results, with the adjacent column pointing to the time beside it but formatted as general.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of field to Date-Time, then you can make it. Right click on the field and look for type or properties

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. That column is already a time column...
I know this seems super simple but I can't figure out why it's not working